# value not populating to kendo dropdown

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, ilist, kendo-combobox

I have a MVC View with Kendo UI that binds value from a ListObject. When the data is fetched from xml file the Kendo Dropdown binds the value but the data is fetched from a table of a database its not binding the value to the dropdown. But the List which has values and returned to the bind function of Dropdown is haveing the values.

The values are binded in Json Format.

```
//Controller Code that returns value to Kendo Dropdown in View

public JsonResult BindTitles()
{
return Json(_title.GetTitle(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

//Data Interface from Entity Framework

public partial interface ITitle
{
IList<tblTitle> GetTitle();
}

public IList<tblTitle> GetTitle()
{
List<tblTitle> tit = new List<tblTitle>();
tit = dbContext.GetTitle().ToList(); // Here the values are available in the "tit"

return tit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Show the code of the view on which you configured your kendo dropdown. The controller code is not enough to give you the solution.